# How to center several divs within a parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have 3 divs contained within a parent div (`class="row services"`).

How can I make it so that the three `col s12 l3` divs are collectively centered within this parent div?

I've tried using `display:block` and `text-align:center` but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row services">

    <div class="col s12 l3">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <h5><p>Nelson Mazda Tulsa</p> <p>Tulsa, OK</p></h5>
        <p>9902 S. Memorial Dr.</p>
        <p>Tulsa, OK 74133</p>
        <p>866-612-0040</p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdaok.com/mazda-dealer-tulsa-ok/car-dealership-near.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Get Directions</a>
        <p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdaok.com/" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Visit Website</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 l3">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <h5><p>Nelson Mazda Hickory Hollow</p> <p>Antioch, TN</p></h5>
        <p>5300 Mount View Road</p>
        <p>Antioch, TN 37013</p>
        <p>877-708-4449</p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdahh.com/nelson-difference/car-dealership-near.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Get Directions</a>
        <p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdahh.com/" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Visit Website</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 l3">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <h5><p>Nelson Mazda Cool Springs</p> <p>Franklin, TN</p></h5>
        <p>7104 S Springs Drive</p>
        <p>Franklin, TN 37067</p>
        <p>877-708-4456</p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdacs.com/nelson-difference/car-dealership-near.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Get Directions</a>
        <p>
        <a href="http://www.nelsonmazdacs.com/" class="btn waves-effect waves-dark white black-text">Visit Website</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

[image]

Comment: You want to center vertically, horizontally or both?

Comment: @Michael_B horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering is easy with CSS Flexbox.

Here's all you need:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4862pp10/)

More flexbox centering options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: I've been looking at answers here for hours! Others always use either `display:block;` or `text-align: center;`, This is the only thing working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.col s12 l3{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or if you want them in a row:

```
.col s12 l3 {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

I hope that's what you are looking for!